# C# Get Index of first occuarance of a substring

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi I have a string "abc %d ef %g hi %j". And I want to get the index of "%". It should give index of first occurance, i.e 3. Can anybody give me a C# snippet for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why 3? because I see space before %, should be 4?

Comment: ok 4. But I am getting -1. I thought it is cos of multiple ocurances.

Comment: return value -1 of method String.IndexOf indicates that the value is not found in the string. May be you use the wrong string to check for %

Answer (score 4):

The snippet is:

```
int firstOccurence = "abc %d ef %g hi %j".IndexOf("%");
//  firstOccurence will be 4
```

Comment: Will it give index of first occurance? It is giving -1.

Answer (score 3):

The index returned will be 4. C# is has a zero-based index.

```
string foo = "abc %d ef %g hi %j";
int i = foo.IndexOf("%"); // Returns 4
```

**Resources:**

Check out [`String.IndexOf()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx).

**Note:**

Do yourself a favor and review [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and the [FAQ's](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) of StackOverflow. It will make your experience here much more fun!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string str = "abc %d ef %g hi %j";
int index = str.IndexOf('%');
```

**[String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

```
string x = "bc %d ef %g hi %j";
int y = x.IndexOf('%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq version

```
string str = "abc %d ef %g hi %j";
var ind = str.Select((item, index) => new  { Found = item,  Index = index }).Where(it => it.Found=='%').Select( it => it.Index).First();
```